# Catalyst won't let me arrange my displays the way I want

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, amd-catalyst

I want displays one and two to line up on the bottom, but CCC refuses to let me do so. I can arrange them the way I want in Windows or Display Fusion, but not CCC, which results in random arrangment changes whenever Catalyst feels like it.

Video of the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MmQRm2xbSU

Answer (score 0):

The only resolution for the issue that I found was to disable Catalyst at startup.